# copy shell output to array

Tags: bash, shell

i am trying to capture the output of the command fuser into an array in shell script.
based on other similar queries I used below lines in shell.

```
p_list = ( $("fuser -m /mnt/usb") )
```

But i am getting below error

```
./capture.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./capture.sh: line 8: `   p_list = ( $(fuser -m /mnt/usb) )'
```

The fuser output is the process list using the above path as below

```
~# fuser -m /mnt/usb
9261 1089 8526
```

Why is this issue? Any hints. How to i achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any assignment in bash: no spaces around `=`.

```
p_list=( $(fuser -m /mnt/usb) )
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to remove the quotes (") around the command to make it work.
p_list=( $(fuser -m /mnt/usb) )